# Specific htacces redirect exception

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have created a redirection in `.htaccess` file for specific condition:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^page/(.*) /clanky/?sf_paged=$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Example:

someone clicks on this link: `https://example.com/page/2/` and they will be redirected to: `https://example.com/clanky/?sf_paged=2/`

This scenario works perfectly.

Now I need to make an exception for the case if a link will be: `https://example.com/page/2/?s=zemedelec` - (the excluding condition should be `/?s=`), in this case I don't want to use any redirection.

Any idea, how to make this exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make an exception on your existing rule for when the query string starts with the URL parameter `s=` then you can add the following *condition* (`RewriteCond` directive):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^s=
RewriteRule ^page/(.*) /clanky/?sf_paged=$1 [R=301,L]
```

The *negated* condition `!^s=` is successful when the query string does not start with `s=`.

> (the excluding condition should be `/?s=`)

The above does not explicitly check that the URL-path ends in a slash, so it will also exclude requests of the form `https://xxx.cz/page/2?s=zemedelec`.